# Confused about an integration simplification

Tags: calculus, integration

$$a_n=\frac{1}{\pi}\left[-\int_{-\pi}^0\sin(x)\cos(nx)\,dx+\int_0^{\pi}\sin(x)\cos(nx)\,dx\right]$$
More convenient to write 
$$a_n=\frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^{\pi}\sin(x)\cos(nx)\,dx.$$

I am confused as to how that the first half of the integral equals the second half.

If I flip the limits, that get rids of the negative sign of the first integral, however the limits are not the same so I can't add them. If I flip the signs of the limit, wouldn't the minus sign be reintroduced leading to 0? (I know that is wrong I just don't know why)

Thank you.

Comment: symmetry in $\sin$ and $\cos$.

Comment: Please don't use external image hosts because it can be unstable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We do a change of variables in the first integral; let $x'=-x$, then
$$\int_{-\pi}^0 -\sin(x)\cos(nx)d x = \int_{-\pi}^0\sin(-x)\cos(-nx)d x \\= -\int_{\pi}^0 \sin(x')\cos(nx')dx' = \int_0^{\pi}\sin(x')\cos(nx')d x'$$
So this integral is in fact equal to the other one:
$$a_n = \frac{1}{\pi}\left(\int_0^\pi \sin(x)\cos(nx)d x + \int_0^\pi \sin(x)\cos(nx)d x \right) = \frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^\pi\sin(x)\cos(nx)d x$$

Comment: Okay, but I don't follow the final bit, your variables are now x' and not x (as x' is -x) so how do you add them together? Is this because cos(-nx) = cos (nx) and sin(x) = sin(-x) when x is pi or 0?

Comment: @Junaid The integrand (the variable over which we integrate) is a so called dummy-variable; it has no meaning. So it doesn't matter whether we integrate over $x'$ or $x$, it means the same thing. As long as the limits of your integral are the same, you can add them together.

Comment: Yup I just realised that as this comment appeared, I greatly appreciate the help. Thank you.